# Visual Studio 2022 | The Profile "..." cannot be executed by the Project

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I'm german but i translated the error in english. So my Problem is that i wanted to use Visual Studio 2022 but when i run a program like a simple code i get this error and btw. I'm using C# and .Net 5.0 because .Net 6.0 seems pretty strange because there are no methods, classes and so on:

> The Profile "..." cannot be executed by the Project

But then i downloaded Visual Studio 2019 and it worked perfectly?
I don't know what the Problem is. Can someone help me?
Please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! I haven't installed .Net Desktopdeveloping! I dont know why but yeah

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the console application with the subtitle:

"A project for creating a command-line application that can run on .NET Core on Windows, Linux and MacOS." [Image showing  which one you should select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdIll.png)

(since you are using the german version: "Ein Projekt zum Erstellen einer Befehlszeilenanwendung, die mit .NET unter Windows, Linux und macOS ausgeführt werden kann.")

The other one will not run.